# How to create transparent slider in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I am trying to create a slider whose thumb is transparent. Idea here is, i want a slider with some labels and icon behind it. When my slider (thumb) comes on top of label/icons, the labels/icons are visible through the thumb of slider.

May be i have to use css or some other way ? I am not sure how to actually achieve it.
I am attaching an image of what i want to achieve.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Your picture does not look as if **Transparency** is what you want to achieve. It looks more like your (number) scale is painted on top of the slider; with something like an `XOR` drawing mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set opacity for slider and it will make it transparent...javafx every control have a opacity property...you can use it

like this

```
Slider sb = new Slider();
sb.setOpacity(0.25);
```